# Possible to get keyframes to work with transition type?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

```
          <motion.div className="flex gap-x-4"
            animate={{y: [100, 30, 0], x: [30, 30,  0],
            scale: [1.4, 1.4, 1.0]}}
            transition={{ duration: 2 , delay: 3.0}}
            style={{ transformOrigin: "center center" }}>
              <Image
                  src="/control-ani.svg"
                  alt="controller"
                  width={18}
                  height={26}
                  className=""
              />
              <h1>different use cases</h1>
            </motion.div>
```

I currently am using key frames to cycle three stages of an animation primarily the key difference being three points on the y-axis being changed. When I try and animate this using a transition like:

```
transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 100, damping: 10 }}
```

It immediately skips to just one smooth transition to the final Y value instead of the typical interval animation without that type being applied. Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const controls = useAnimation();



  useEffect(() => {
    const animateSequence = async () => {
      const yValues = [30, 0];
      const scaleVal = [1.25, 1.0]
      const xOffset = [20, 0]
      for (let i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++) {
        await controls.start({ y: yValues[i], x: xOffset[i], scale: scaleVal[i], transition: { type: "spring", stiffness: 450, damping: 30, delay: i === 0 ? 1.9 : 1.5, duration: 4}});
      }
    };

    animateSequence();
  }, [controls]);
```

I was able to fix this using a for loop to create a seperate animation for each y value.